# How can I migrate amazon linux from VERSION_ID="2018.03" to version 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux-2

I have been working on python project on AWS EC2 instance using Amazon Linux VERSION_ID="2018.03"  but I need to migrate entire OS to latest version 2 as older version is missing some important features and commands.....
how can I do that
I checked

```
$ cat /etc/os-release and found
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
```

Answer (score 1):

we have to create a new Linux 2 instance and do a manual migration.

> From: Amazon Linux
>
> If you are currently using the Amazon Linux AMI, we recommend that you
> migrate to Amazon Linux 2. To migrate to Amazon Linux 2, launch an
> instance or create a virtual machine using the current image. Install
> your application on Amazon Linux 2, plus any packages required by your
> application. Test your application, and make any changes required for
> it to run on Amazon Linux 2.